# "android:maxSdkVersion" is not working

Tags: android

Preparing application with following configuration:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:maxSdkVersion="18"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17"
    android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

But application installing properly on lollipop devices. Can anyone explain the matter why this is occurred.

Comment: are you using android studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`android:maxSdkVersion` is no longer checked beyond Android 2.0.1 as stated by developer.google.com:

> Future versions of Android (beyond Android 2.0.1) will no longer check
>   or enforce the maxSdkVersion attribute during installation or
>   re-validation. Google Play will continue to use the attribute as a
>   filter, however, when presenting users with applications available for
>   download.
>
> Reference:
>   http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#max

Answer (score 1):

### Switch To Android Studio

**android:maxSdkVersion — Specifies the maximum API Level on which the application is able to run.**

> Warning: Declaring this attribute is not recommended. First, there is
>   no need to set the attribute as means of blocking deployment of your
>   application onto new versions of the Android platform as they are
>   released. By design, new versions of the platform are fully
>   backward-compatible. Your application should work properly on new
>   versions, provided it uses only standard APIs and follows development
>   best practices. Second, note that in some cases, declaring the
>   attribute can result in your application being removed from users'
>   devices after a system update to a higher API Level. Most devices on
>   which your application is likely to be installed will receive periodic
>   system updates over the air, so you should consider their effect on
>   your application before setting this attribute.

Future versions of ***Android (beyond Android 2.0.1)*** will no longer check or enforce the **maxSdkVersion** attribute during installation or re-validation. Google Play will continue to use the attribute as a filter, however, when presenting users with applications available for download.

1. [Read Official Document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)